# Redux states structure

Tags: reactjs

Hello i have a reducer that has 2 initial states messages and waitResponse, message is an object that contains the messages and the type of each message (user or bot) but I have a problem with how to structure my redux

my reducer:

```
const initalState = [
  {
    messages: [],
    waitResponse: false,
  },
];

const messageReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ON_MESSAGE:
      return{...state, messages: [...state, {type: 'user', text: action.text}]}

    case BOT_MESSAGE:
      return{...state, messages: [...state, {type: 'bot', text: action.text}]}
    case FINISH:
      return [
        {
          ...state,
          waitResponse: false,
        },
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default messageReducer;
```

i got this states:

```
0: {…}, messages: Array(2)} 
0: {messages: Array(0), waitResponse: false} messages: Array(2) 
0: {messages: Array(0), waitResponse: false} 1: {type: "user", text: "a"}
```

my action:

```
export const sendMessage = text => ({
  type: ON_MESSAGE,
  text
});

export const botMessage = text => ({
  type: BOT_MESSAGE,
  text
});

export const awaitAwnser = () => ({
  type: AWAIT_MESSAGE,
});
export const finish = () => ({
  type: FINISH,
});
export const checkMessage = text => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(sendMessage(text));

    dispatch(awaitAwnser());
    //start bot checkout message

    dispatch(botMessage(verify(text)));

    dispatch(finish());
  };
};
```

e também tenho problemas em como mostrar isso em meu jsx:

```
 <Styled.ChatLog>
        {chat.map(messages => (
          <Styled.MessageWrapper user={messages.user}>
            <Styled.BotImg src={BotLogo} user={messages.user} />
            <Styled.ChatMessage user={messages.user}>
              {messages.messages}
            </Styled.ChatMessage>
          </Styled.MessageWrapper>
        ))}
        <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
      </Styled.ChatLog>
```

Comment: You merge `state` in two different places; why?

Comment: why I'm not knowing how to just state a message array and the message type

and whether it is waiting or not.

Comment: i edit with my action

Comment: My point is that you're destructuring `state` into the top-level object, then *again* into the `messages` array. You likely meant to destructure `state.messages` into the new `messages` property.

Comment: Can you help me ? I'm a little confused and I'm also not able to display on my jsx

Comment: Have you figured it out @gabriel?

Comment: not yet brother:(

Comment: @Niyongabo can helpme please?

Comment: @gabriel please check out my support. feel free to visit my repo https://github.com/NiyongaboEric/chat-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I configure react with redux. More information please feel free to use my GitHub repository https://github.com/NiyongaboEric/chat-app[1](https://github.com/NiyongaboEric/chat-app)

**Prerequisites**

- Install redux dev tools devtools [Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en)

  #### step 1

  Create redux store

```js
// app.js or routers.js

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';  

// we want all data to be available in all components

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>   // we need to configure store globally
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage} /> . // import inside your components
          </switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
```

### step 2

Since our component has access to the store, It is easy to access the data. We 
  are going to connect our `jsx` or `js` react component. 
  It is time to connect our action from the component so that we can update or add data to the store

1. Import your action
2. Save action into `mapDispatchToProps`. If you do your action will be available as props.
3. Use `componentDidMount` to dispatch your action.
4. Use `componentDidUpdate` to use returned data. Make sure to use if condition to compare new props with previous props.
5. We use `mapStateToProps` to access the data from store. We shall receive them as state and return them as props.

```js
// I am using LandingPage component please feel free to change it.

`LandingPage.js`


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { checkMessage } from '../../redux/actions/singleAccommodation';  // here import your actions

export class LandingPage extends Component {

  state = {
      message: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { checkMessage } = this.props;
    checkMessage(you may pass data);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { checkMessage } = this.props;
    if (this.props.checkMessage.id !== prevProps.checkMessage.id) {
      this.setState({ message: 'I am a new data, feel free to use me' });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <p>welcome home</>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    checkMessage: state.keyNameOfReducer, // store.landingReducer
  };
};

export const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getUserProfile,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LandingPage);
```

- step 3
  Here we going to configure redux

  `store.js`

```js
// remember to import store in `app.js` or `routers.js` and use it as props.

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';
import initialState from './initialState';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk);

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composeWithDevTools(middleware));

export default store;
```

`initialState.js`

```js
const initalState = [
  {
    messages: [],
    waitResponse: false,
  },
];
```

- step 4

  We need to create a reducer but It is good to combine reducers. As app growing you will need different reducers.

  `reducer/index.js`

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import landingReducer from './landingReducer' // import as many reducer as you can 

export default combineReducers({
  landingReducer: landingReducer,   // this is the name you will call and access 
  the data in your component
```

- Step 6
  Add your reducer file, mine is landingReducer

```js
const messageReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ON_MESSAGE:
      return {...state, messages: 'After here I am going to stay for a while in th store'}


    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default messageReducer;
```

- Step 6
  We need action so that we can update the current data

```js
export const checkMessage = text => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(ON_MESSAGE, text);   // If your action name is not ON_MESSAGE, reducer will not update the store. 

  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake constructing reducer.

```
const initalState = [
  {
    messages: [],
    waitResponse: false,
  },
];

const messageReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ON_MESSAGE:
      return{...state, messages: [...state.messages, {type: 'user', text: action.text}]}

    case BOT_MESSAGE:
      return{...state, messages: [...state.messages, {type: 'bot', text: action.text}]}
    case FINISH:
      return [
        {
          ...state,
          waitResponse: false,
        },
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default messageReducer;
```

Comment: i got this: state.messages is not iterable

Comment: const initalState = {
    messages: [],
    waitResponse: false,
  };
// Please use this. Remove []

Comment: could you help me how would i display this on jsx? i have problem to show this :        {chat.messages.map(messages => (
          <Styled.MessageWrapper user={messages.user}>
            <Styled.BotImg src={BotLogo} user={messages.user} />
            <Styled.ChatMessage user={messages.user}>
              {messages.messages}
            </Styled.ChatMessage>
          </Styled.MessageWrapper>
        ))}

Comment: You have to use mapStateToProps.
const mapStateToProps = store => ({
  messages: store.messageReducer.messages
})

connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName)

And in jsx file you can iterate this.props.messages

Comment: Yes. Where did you define a variable 'chat'?

Comment: i use functional component, is my const chat = useSelector(state => state.Chat);

Comment: i got this with console.log(chat): Object
messages: []
waitResponse: false